# Check if a String Ends with a Number in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers

I'm trying to implement the function below. Would it be best to use some type of regex here? I need to capture the number too.

```
function endsWithNumber($string) {
  $endsWithNumber = false;

  // Logic

  return $endsWithNumber;
}
```

Comment: Since it's only one character, it's actually probably best to not bother using regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$test="abc123";
//$test="abc123n";
$r = preg_match_all("/.*?(\d+)$/", $test, $matches);
//echo $r;
//print_r($matches);
if($r>0) {
    echo $matches[count($matches)-1][0];
}
```

the regex is explained as follows:

.*? - this will take up all the characters in the string from the start up until a match for the subsequent part is also found.

(\d+)$ - this is one or more digits up until the end of the string, grouped.

without the ? in the first part, only the last digit will be matched in the second part because all digits before it would be taken up by the .*

Answer (score 29):

`return is_numeric(substr($string, -1, 1));`

This only checks to see if the last character in the string is numerical, if you want to catch and return multidigit numbers, you might have to use a regex.

An appropriate regex would be `/[0-9]+$/` which will grab a numerical string if it is at the end of a line.

Comment: For the regex, you can replace [0-9] with \d

Comment: And for the first character, you can just switch it to return `is_numeric(substr($string, 0, 1));`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid potential undefined index error use

```
is_numeric($code[strlen($code) - 1])
```

instead.

Comment: Good short code, But If the `$code` string is empty. will throw a Warning:  Uninitialized string offset -1. you need to add a test to check if the string is empty, could you please see my answer I handle this case!

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion The simple way to find a string ends with number is

```php
    $string = "string1";
    $length = strlen($string)-1;
    if(is_numeric($string[$length]))
    {
       echo "String Ends with Number";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly,* Take the length of string, and check if it is equal to zero *(empty)* then `return false`. *Secondly,* check with built-in function on the last character *`$len-1`*.

> `is_numeric(var)` returns boolean whether a variable is a numeric string or not.

```php
function endsWithNumber($string){
    $len = strlen($string);
    if($len === 0){
        return false;
    }
    return is_numeric($string[$len-1]);
}
```

**Tests*:*

```php
var_dump(endsWithNumber(""));
var_dump(endsWithNumber("str123"));
var_dump(endsWithNumber("123str"));
```

**Results*:*

```php
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function startsWithNumber(string $input):bool
{
      $out = false; //assume negative response, to avoid using else
      if(strlen($input)) {
        $out = is_numeric($input[0]); //only if string is not empty, do this to avoid index related errors.
      }
      
      return $out;
}
```