# Check if a String Starts with a Number in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a String Ends with a Number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114609/check-if-a-string-ends-with-a-number-in-php)

I'm trying to implement the function below. Would it be best to use some type of regex here? I need to capture the number too.

```
function startsWithNumber($string) {
  $startsWithNumber = false;

  // Logic

  return $startsWithNumber;
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Check if a String Ends with a Number in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114609/check-if-a-string-ends-with-a-number-in-php)

Comment: This is practically the same question as your last one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114609/check-if-a-string-ends-with-a-number-in-php.  Didn't you think the answer to that would also solve this?  And no, please don't use a regex to check a single character of a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like to this may work to you:

```
function str2int($string) {
  $length = strlen($string);   
  for ($i = 0, $int = ''; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($string[$i]))
        $int .= $string[$i];
     else break;
  }

  return (int) $int;
}
```

Comment: Or the simple 1 line `preg_match` in the other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114620/1992193

Comment: If you're just looking for the first character, strings can be seen as character arrays.  To access the first character you can quickly use the [] operator at position zero. e.g. `is_numeric($string[0])`

Answer (score 32):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) and [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit):

```
function startsWithNumber($string) {
    return strlen($string) > 0 && ctype_digit(substr($string, 0, 1));
}
```

The additional `strlen` is just required as `ctype_digit` returns *true* for an empty string before PHP 5.1.

Or, if you rather want to use a regular expression:

```
function startsWithNumber($str) {
    return preg_match('/^\d/', $str) === 1;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach more.. Very simple

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thank you, helped me a lot!

Comment: The first solution can be simplified by avoiding the use of `strlen` and `substr` as follows: `return $string !== '' && ctype_digit($string[0]);`